# Impossible to access the site administration

Tags: wp-admin, user-access

I have the following issue in the WordPress: When I connect with the administrator account, the page mysite.com/wp-admin/ gives the error message:

*You do not have sufficient permissions to access this admin page. Reason: The current user doesn't have the "read" capability that is required to access the "Dashboard" menu item.*

But when I go, as I am still logged, to the page mysite.com, **I can see the administrator bar on the top of the screen**.

So there is still some link between the user and its administration role but I am not able to access any page in /wp-admin/.

I already tried to add new user with admin rights directly in the database (wp_users & wp_usermeta tables) with phpMyAdmin but without success. I also tried to disable all plugins via FTP but no success neither.

I didn't change the prefixes. And I checked in the database, it looks fine. IN the wp_capabilities in the wp_usermeta, the value is "a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}". I already tried all the "fix proposals" that I found on the internet but without success. I replaced the value in the wp_user_roles in the WP_options table by the wordpress default value... And still the same issue.

Any ideas please? Thank you!

Comment: did u tried to create a page or post from admin bar

Comment: Yes, I did. I see the different types of content I can create as Admin (even the custom content that is not in the default WP installation) but as it redirects to example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php, I get the same error. I have the this message for everything in "/wp-admin/..."

Comment: try re installing forlders wp-admin and wp-includes

Comment: That I already did as well - I reinstalled the WP and I also verified the files permissions. I think that must come somewhere from the database...